# Empathy not showing in messageing menu

Tags: empathy, messaging-menu

I just installed 12.10 and noticed that, even if I added more than one account to Online Accounts and I'm actually using empathy to chat, it is not present in Messaging Menu or in any other point of the tray.

This means that if i close it, it remains open but inaccessible and I have to start it again from dash.

How can i integrate it in messaging menu (shouldn't this be the default?) or, at least, make it showing me a tray icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Dash and type `Startup Applications`. Activate the `Chat` service. If you don't have it you can create it with:

Name: Chat

Command: telepathy-indicator

Description: Telepathy Indicator Service

Comment: That should have worked, but I reinstalled the whole operating system because it was too unstable.